# Incomplete Json - Behance API

Tags: json, ajax, behance-api

I'm working with the Behance API to build a plugin. I got the API key and built the URL to get my project list data in JSON format.

The weird thing is that, the JSON is not complete at all, there are many project missing, 14 missing to be specific.

Does someone have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here: https://help.behance.net/hc/en-us/community/posts/202357274-Number-of-Behance-API-request-results-limited-to-25-

It seems that by default the number of items is limited to 25. To get more you need to paginate adding a query get after the URL.

ex: http://www.behance.net/v2/users/gokhanaltinigne/projects?api_key=##&per_page=25&page=2